# Is it an overkill to add external integrity check to the AES-GCM encoding?

Tags: aes, hmac, cbc, gcm, integrity

There is a java library for android which implements integrity checking to predefined encrypting mode(which can be found [here](https://github.com/tozny/java-aes-crypto)).

> Short class description from [author page](http://tozny.com/blog/encrypting-strings-in-android-lets-make-better-mistakes/) to avoid further questions about code.
>
> - Algorithm & Mode: AES 128, CBC, and PKCS5 padding. We use a 128 bit key size for its widespread support and because it’s not clear that
>     256 is stronger. We would have picked GCM for its built-in integrity
>     checking, but that’s only available since Android Jelly Bean, which
>     leaves out about 1/4 of active Android devices
> - IV Handling: We securely generate a random IV before each encryption.
> - Key generation: Random or pasword-based.
> - Integrity: We’ve also added more-or-less transparent integrity checking in the form of a SHA 256 MAC with a constant-time equality
>     check. This is in the form of a “combined key” where 128 bits of the
>     key are used for encryption and 256 bits are used for integrity, then
>     the keys are kept together.

As stated before, it's possible to use AES-GCM, which already have built-in integrity checking.

So, the question is: **Are there any (dis)advantages of adding external integrity check to AES-GCM (in theory, or practically)?**

To sum up already mentioned comments:

> Disadvantages:
>
> - loosing the speed advantage of AES-GCM;
> - performance/space use and extra complexity(i don't think that complexity is the case, as library is fairly simple);
> - human factor:
>
>   - *"Crypto is tricky: it’s hard to tell that the gibberish that’s being printed is not good crypto, and it’s hard to tell that the code example you picked up from {put any source name here you like} has serious flaws."*
>
> Advantages:
>
> - HMAC-SHA256 has stronger authentication than GCM(in-depth explanation [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24379/security-of-integrity-protection-with-hmac-vs-aead)), among other things not leaking the key in case of nonce reuse

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Security of integrity protection with HMAC vs AEAD](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24379/security-of-integrity-protection-with-hmac-vs-aead)

Comment: That library adds HMAC-SHA256 on top of the cipher so the duplicate I linked should answer your question, at least about the advantage. The disadvantages would be performance/space use and extra complexity.

Comment: besides loosing the speed advantage of AES-GCM over AES-CTR+HMAC (or whatever they use)? no, I don't know any.

Answer (score 5):

Theoretically, there is no issue adding some kind of MAC on top of authenticated encryption's builtin. **However**, in practice there might be subtle flaws with composing the particular primitives you're using, or you may make an implementation flaw that renders them both vulnerable to a side-channel attack that didn't exist previously. Ultimately, it's best to stay away from getting creative with protocol design - just use the best-known implementation of the best-known primitive for the job.

Comment: In a nutshell, using more than the minimum amount of crypto necessary is more likely to weaken security than improve it.

Comment: This does not mention any of the advantages.

Comment: What advantages?

Comment: @pg1989 HMAC-SHA256 has stronger authentication than GCM, among other things not leaking the key in case of nonce reuse.

Comment: If you're gonna do two-pass authenticated encryption, why not just CBC+HMAC?

Comment: @pg1989 the question was about possible cons and pros of HMAC over GCM. and if two-pass auth encryption you mean HMAC over AES-CBC,  then mentioned lib actually does that by default. About "it's best to stay away from getting creative with protocol design" i agree, however, even if there is some mistake in authors algoritm what consequencies can be there as hashed message was already encrypted and protected by key?

Comment: Moreover, it is one of the reasons why i asked this question here - most competent place in this matter. Another reason was the fact, that i couldn't find any disscussion about two-pass authenticated encryption.